# LEFT JOIN NOT SHOW ALL LEFT JOIN ROWS

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

A LEFT JOIN should show all rows on the left table however when running the following query, I am only getting place values where there is a same id.
Please can someone give me some guidance as to where I might be going wrong:

```
SELECT us.*, sp.date , k.kelas as nama_kelas
FROM gtech_tbl_user_siswa us
JOIN sekolah_tbl_kelas k ON k.id = us.kelas
LEFT OUTER JOIN gtech_tbl_absensi_siswa_pertemuan sp ON us.id = sp.id_user 
WHERE sp.id_materi = 520
AND sp.id_sub_materi = 1206
```

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the criteria on the *right* table which currently appear in the `WHERE` clause to the `ON` clause of the left join involving that table:

```
SELECT *
FROM gtech_tbl_user_siswa us
INNER JOIN sekolah_tbl_kelas k ON k.id = us.kelas
LEFT OUTER JOIN gtech_tbl_absensi_siswa_pertemuan sp
    ON us.id = sp.id_user AND sp.id_materi = 520 AND sp.id_sub_materi = 1206;
```

The issue you are having is due to that the `WHERE` clause happens *after* the left join.  So, even though your left join does in fact spare non matching records on the left side of the join from being filtered off, the `WHERE` clause later would remove such records anyway.